# date format for a large datafile

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe named return like this

```
date  AAPL.High   ABT.High ABBV.High   ACN.High  ADBE.High
1 2007-01-03         NA         NA        NA         NA         NA
2 2007-01-04 -0.7302264  1.5242975        NA  0.6196975 -0.7774578
3 2007-01-05  0.2440017 -0.4788517        NA -0.6467282 -0.2442004
```

Now when I tries to set date by using this formula

```
return$date <- as.Date(return$date,format="%y-%m-%d")
```

it eliminates dates and produce a file like this

```
date  AAPL.High   ABT.High ABBV.High   ACN.High  ADBE.High ADT.High
1 <NA>         NA         NA        NA         NA         NA       NA
2 <NA> -0.7302264  1.5242975        NA  0.6196975 -0.7774578       NA
3 <NA>  0.2440017 -0.4788517        NA -0.6467282 -0.2442004       NA
```

any solution?

Comment: It's uppercase `Y`, `format="%Y-%m-%d"`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas Thank you so much. Now it is working